# how to overwrite only a portion of the array?

Tags: python, numpy

i have an array that contains labels, for instance

```
    X1 = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0]
    X1 = np.array(X1)
```

I also have an array X2 that contains the updated labels for label [1] in X1, for instance.

```
    X2 = [-1, 1, -1, -1]
    X2 = np.array(X2)
```

how to overwrite X1 for all labels equal to [1] to be X2?
The output should look like:

```
    New_X1 = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -1, 3, 2, 3, -1, 0]
```

I tried something like this:

```
    New_X1 = [np.where(X1==1)]= X2
```

This obviously didn't work.
Any help, please.

Comment: Are your arrays really lists (as you've written them down) or are they numpy arrays?

Comment: Assuming that `X1` and `X2` are numpy arrays (if they are not first do `X1 = np.array(X1)` and `X2 = np.array(X2)`) do `X1[X1 == 1] = X2`. if you need it to be a new array fist do `New_X1 = X1.copy()` and then `New_X1[X1 == 1] = X2`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the lists you've written down are indeed NumPy arrays, you are not indexing into `New_X1` properly.  It should be:

```
New_X1[np.where(X1 == 1)] = X2
```

However, you can achieve the same thing with logical indexing instead.  It's not only cleaner, but faster:

```
New_X1[X1 == 1] = X2
```

Comment: Yes, because `X1 == 1` contains 4 values that are equal to 1, but `X2` has 11 elements.  This naturally will not work.  Can you please update your question so that it reflects the actual inputs you're using?  This begs the question now - suppose that you only find 4 elements that are equal to 1, yet `X2` doesn't contain 4 elements.  What do you do here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice and concise way to accomplish your task through **`map()`**:

```
New_X1 = list(map(lambda x1: x1 if x1 != 1 else X2.pop(0), X1))
```

**EDIT:**
I've seen you edited your post specifying that the sequences are np arrays: you can easily adapt this implementation to that case too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your feedback. All correct.
Here is what i did, based on your feedback.

```
    New_X1 = X1.copy()
    New_X1[X1 == 1] = X2
```